# dcm4che dcmqr cmove is writing to the default storage directory instead of the directory path specified in the -cstoredest option

Tags: dcm4che

I am trying to run this command:

```
dcmqr -L SEHATYPACS:104 -cmove SEHATYPACS -I DICOM_QR_SCP@10.221.21.111:7840 -qStudyInstanceUID=1.2.124.113532.10.210.5.12.20090321.114039.3256166 -cstore 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1 -cstoredest C:\temp2\X-RAY
```

The command executes successfully and brings 3 matches. However, the moved images are not written to the storage directory specified in `-cstoredest` option. Instead, the images are written to the default storage directory defined in the JBoss JMX Management Console under `"group=ONLINE_STORAGE,service=FileSystemMgt".`

As you notice the command is using the `-cstore` option using the SOP Class UID of the image.

I need those images to override the default storage directory and use the one in the `-cstoredest` option.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a DCM4CHEE archive running on this machine with an AE of SEHATYPACS?

I expect, the AE you are requesting from (DICOM_QR_SCP) already has the AE title SEHATYPACS defined and pointing to port 11112 (or whatever you have DCM4CHEE configured to use).

I think you have a couple options: one, stop DCM4CHEE and use its port number for your listener in the command you have (dcmqr -L SEHATYPACS:11112 ...); or two, use a different AE title for your -L flag (this likely will require you to define that AE in your DICOM_QR_SCP location).